# If $(\mathbb Z,*)$ is invertible and has cancellation property, does it imply that is associative?

Tags: group-theory, associativity

If $(\mathbb Z,*)$ is invertible and has cancellation property, does it imply that is associative?

I know that if is invertible and has associative, then is a group and has cancellation property. But I'm confused, Can I say it is associative, only known that is invertible and has cancellation?

Comment: What do you mean by "invertible" here? The natural class of non-associative group-like objects is the class of quasigroups (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

Comment: I mean that has a neutral element, and every element has an inverse.

Comment: So what is the "cancellation property", beside invertibility?

Comment: I don't know :(

Answer (score 3):

Any kind of non-associative [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) where each element has an inverse will do as a counter-example. This includes all non-associative [Moufang loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moufang_loop), such as the non-zero [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion).

Comment: So isn't possible only with knowing those two conditions?

Comment: @Annai Correct.

Comment: I don't think this answer answers the asker at the level of the asker